# Getting a view by changing url in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, routes

I have a problem in the file `RouteConfig.cs` in my asp.net mvc4 application :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Admin",
               url: "Admin",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Administration" }
           );
        }
```

in the `home` controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
         return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Administration()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and added the view :

[image: views]

but when i put `http://localhost:61961/Admin` as url the view is not found.

Why this happens? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Routing config is ordered. please move your administration-Config to the top of RegisterRoutes.

Right now you would be mapped to

> Controller: admin
>   View: index

as your default routing catches your `localhost:{port}/admin`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Admin",
       url: "Admin",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Administration" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```